# Prevent sheets renaming, moving and deletion

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook consisting of 44 sheets. In this workbook, I have a VBA code that **protects and unprotects** the sheets,  **hides and unhides** sheets, **inserts and deletes** inserted sheets.

How do I protect the workbook such that a user doesn't **delete**, **rename** or even **move** the sheets?

I tried the **protect workbook structure** but it prevents insertion of sheets. How do I go about this?

Comment: Cna't you lock the sheets with password, by right-click and selecting "Protect sheet"? Tick all the boxes and enter a password.

Comment: why not create a macro that will unprotect the workbook, add a page, give the user a msgbox to change sheet name, and then reprotect the workbook? You can add a macro button in the ribbon.

Comment: @Kleven The sheets (24 of them) are password protected. The unprotected sheets contain pivot tables and other stuff but are very hidden. Right-clicking and password-protecting a sheet does not prevent a user from renaming, moving or deleting such sheet.

Comment: @JohnSUN Instructing the user has to be my last resort if nothing else works.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is rename and move the Sheet any time it is activated. Each worksheet has a worksheet name(Sheet1) and a Caption("MyWorksheet"). If the user changes the caption, you will not be able to reference the caption, so reference the sheet name instead. You can set a sheet name or just reference the default sheet name. In the VBA IDE, in the VBAProject open the Micorsoft Excel Objects folder in the Project window, and open the sheet instead of the Modules. In the dropdown at the top select Worksheet, then in the second drop down on the right select Activate. This will generate the following code, or you could just copy paste the following into the page. I added the renaming of the sheet caption and the move sheet code.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    On Error Resume Next
    Sheet5.Name = "TEST"
    Sheet5.Move After:=Sheet1
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Now anytime someone clicks the sheet, the sheet will be renamed to its original name and moved to where you want it in the workbook.

Comment: Thanks. This is an excellent idea, but hope this little code on every sheet (24 of them) will not impact on performance every time a sheet is activated. By the way, what about restriction on sheet deletion. This aspect is of utmost concern as a single deleted sheet can cause others to fail.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to still protect the workbook, you can do this. You would have to add a button in the ribbon, worksheet, or a keyboard shortcut for the user to run it.

```
Sub newSheet()
Dim sheetName As Variant
    sheetName = InputBox("What do you want to name the sheet?")
    ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect 'password if needed
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = sheetName
    ActiveWorkbook.Protect Structure:=True, Windows:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Firstly, the user need not rename any sheet. The only renaming done is by a macro when the user wants to print. Secondly, if the workbook structure is protected, my VBA code that duplicates, renames and deletes sheets will not work.

Comment: What is your code that duplicates? Add the code in your question and I will show you how to do it.